# Right method to check if DateTime is greater than another DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, for-loop

I want to check if a DateTime in CustomFormat is greater than another DateTime, but the checking is okay after that the code removes a lot of item and none of that correct. Here is my code. The job is to remove any ListViewItem which is older than 3 days.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lvValid.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) > DateTime.Parse(lvValid.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text))
    {
        lvValid.Items[i].Remove();
    }
}
```

I've already tried foreach but it didn't help. And its removing every second element, but its not correct

Comment: "in customformat", have you verified that the values you parsed are parsed correctly?

Comment: Can you show an example of `lvValid.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text`? What format is it in?

Comment: Also, that loop will at most remove every other item as once you remove one item the following items move up one index, which you then skip.

Comment: usually one would use a backward running loop to remove items

Comment: lvValid.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text example is: 2019.08.06 8:50:43

Comment: how do you populate your listview? why aren't you working with the real data instead of fiddling around in the view?

Comment: `DateTime.Now <= DateTime.Parse(text).AddDays(3);` tried this ?

Comment: For extra security, may I suggest you consider using `DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue)` before comparing, in case the user input is not verified to be appropriately parsable. Beyond that, you may also want to consider looping backwards using `i--`, as you hot-remove items in the loop thus changing indexing.

Comment: Or use while instead of for and remove or increment i, depending on the test, tend to find that more comprehensible myself.

Comment: Btw. you might want to declare the "cutoff" outside the `for` loop, so you don't need to calculate it all the time. For debugging it might be interesting to store the parsed `DateTime` in a temporary variable, so you can more easily see, what the actual value is. Also, in the `if` you might want to express exactly what you want: `if (parsedDate < cutoff) { ... }`. Right now it's flipped and your mind has to reverse it, every time you read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One big problem with a forward loop is that if you remove one item, then the indices of the remaining will shift leftwards. So at `i == 1` the next item will be at `1` after the removal. Then `i` will be incremented and skip the former next item.

I would suggest to use a backward loop:

```
for (int i = lvValid.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) > DateTime.Parse(lvValid.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text))
    {
        lvValid.Items[i].Remove();
    }
}
```

personally I would advice to work with the original data. First filter the data according to your condition and then repopulate the `ListView`.

Comment: Did that fix which items was removed so it now does **everything** correctly?

Comment: Or forward loop but when item is removed do a `i--` to avoid skipping items. Easier to do a backward loop imho.

Comment: @LarryPetshow I am glad to hear that it works. Still I would advise to work on the underlying data model and not on the visual representation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should Reverse for loop & not use `.AddDays(-3)`

```
for (int i = lvValid.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (DateTime.Now <= DateTime.Parse(lvValid.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text).AddDays(3);
    {
        lvValid.Items[i].Remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use *forward* loop (if order of removing matters) you should increment `i++` when you don't remove an item:

```
// we don't want redrawing on each removing (i.e. lvValid blicking)
lvValid.BeginUpdate();

try 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lvValid.Items.Count; ) // don't icrement i here... 
        if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) > DateTime.Parse(lvValid.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text))
            lvValid.Items[i].Remove();
        else 
            ++i; // ... but there
}
finally 
{
    // when finisihing removing, redraw lvValid if required 
    lvValid.EndUpdate();
}
```